# How to create a sine function in c

Tags: c, math

I know there is a `sin` function in `math.h` but I want to make that function on my own, just for fun. I have created `sin` function based on Macluarin expansion of the sine function.
[image]

I wrote a power function and a factorial function, they work correctly from `main`, but they are not working in the `sin` function.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    double y;
    printf("\n\nPlease enter a value to find corresponding sin value\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    y=sin(i);
    printf("\nYour value is\n %f",y);
    return 0;
}
    
double sin(int z)
{
    int i=1;
    double value,val2,val3,sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<33;i+=2)
    {
        val2=power(z,i);
        val3=factorial(i);
        value=val2/val3;
        if(((i-1)/2)%2!=0){
            sum=sum-value;    //((power(x,i))/factorial(i));
        }else
        {
            sum=sum+value;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%f\n",sum);
    return sum;
}

int factorial(int x)
{
    int i,sum=1;
    for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {
        sum = sum*i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int power(int x,int y)
{
    unsigned long long int i,sum=1;
    for(i=1;i<=y;i++)
    {
        sum=sum*x;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Besides overflows, using integers will lead to truncation of decimals. Oh, and you do declare the functions before you call them? You do have function prototypes somewhere above the `main` function?

Comment: what's the purpose of this if condition `if(((i-1)/2)%2!=0)`?

Comment: @ARBY this is for `-` value in series like sum-x^3/3!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula expects values in radians but you're using integers so I'm assuming you give it degrees. That will make the formula give wrong values.

Also you use `int`s as return values from `factorial()` and `power()` which will cause overflows. If you have 32bit machine even giving 2 to your formula will overflow since `int` can only go up to 2^31-1 and your trying to get 2^33.

Also if your compiler doesn't complain that you're returning an `unsigned long long int` from a function that has `int` as a return type please increase the warning level.

Answer (score 5):

`int factorial()` overflows quite quickly. `13!` doesn't fit into 32-bit integer. `21!` doesn't fit into 64-bit integer.

`int power()` seems totally off. Why do you expect an argument `x` to be `int`? BTW, it also overflows quickly.

The (almost) right way to compute McLauren series is to express the next term from the previous one:

```
    term = (-1) * term * (x*x) / ((n+1)*(n+2));
    sum += term;
    n += 2;
```

It shall work, but may lead to numerical instabilities with large `x`. A [Horner schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) is an ultimate answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the standard maths libraries like [fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/) they all do argument reduction. The Macluarin series works best for small values of x. So for large x you want to get x into a small range. Working in radians if we can find y between -pi/2 and pi/2 such that x = y + 2 k pi. Or x = pi - y + 2 k pi.

This will help get y into a small range and mean you need fewer terms of the series to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already stated, it is a bad idea to calculate the `power` and `factorial` part in their own function as it will overflow even for rather small values.

You can try to combine the calculation so that you have a `multiplication` and a `divide` in each loop.

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// This function returns the contribution from the k'th element
double kth_contribution(double x, int k)
{
    int i;
    int s = -1.0;
    double d = 1.0;
    if (k < 0) return 0;
    if (k == 1) return x;
    if (k % 2 == 0) return 0;
    if ((k-1) % 4 == 0) s = 1.0;

    for (i=1; i<=k; ++i)
    {
        d = d * x / i;
    }
    d = s * d;
    return d;
}

int main(void) {
    int k;
    int x = 1.0;
    for (k=0; k<33; ++k)
    {
        printf("k=%d: %0.80f\n", k, kth_contribution(1.0, k));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
k=0: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=1: 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=2: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=3: -0.16666666666666665741480812812369549646973609924316406250000000000000000000000000
k=4: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=5: 0.00833333333333333321768510160154619370587170124053955078125000000000000000000000
k=6: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=7: -0.00019841269841269841252631711547849135968135669827461242675781250000000000000000
k=8: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=9: 0.00000275573192239858925109505932704578867742384318262338638305664062500000000000
k=10: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=11: -0.00000002505210838544172022386617932135366437762513669440522789955139160156250000
k=12: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=13: 0.00000000016059043836821615925802332523156679827680548555690620560199022293090820
k=14: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=15: -0.00000000000076471637318198174152558028953378813433183758263567142421379685401917
k=16: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
k=17: 0.00000000000000281145725434552099254097088490189675684814327692728763707918915316

....
```

Now you just need to add all contribution together.